# Console returning null value outside the block but gives correct value inside it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The second `console.log()` returns me the correct value but the first one isn't. Why is it so? Can someone help me out?

```
angular.module('resultsApp', ['ngCookies'])

    .config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
        $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
    }])



      .controller('resultsController', function($scope) {
        var code = localStorage.getItem('code');
        $scope.data = "";

            var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("0/"+code);

            dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                $scope.data = snapshot.val();
            });
            console.log($scope.data)
      });
```

Comment: This is a very common question when dealing with asynchronous code. Your second console.log is called before the the data has returned from firebase. That’s the way async code works - the second console log does not wait until the on value event has fired.

Comment: So, how do i make them synchronous? But even though, i was wondering why the data in my frontend is not loading even after data is completely retrieved from firebase?

Comment: Since it is asynchronous, I recommend dealing with the `$scope.data` operations inside your `on('value')` function.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93

Answer (score 0):

You code will be executed in following order in the most cases

```
exec 1--> $scope.data = "";

exec 2--> var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("0/"+code);

exec 3--> dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { //register event and wait for response asyncronousnly
exec 5-->     console.log(snapshot.val());
exec 6-->     $scope.data = snapshot.val();
});
exec 4--> console.log($scope.data) //at this moment value of $scope.data = ""
```

So what you can do is move your code in a function(`let processData`) which you want to execute after getting the data and then call it like this

```
angular.module('resultsApp', ['ngCookies'])

.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}])

.controller('resultsController', function($scope) {
    var code = localStorage.getItem('code');
    $scope.data = "";

        var dataRef = firebase.database().ref("0/"+code);

        dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            $scope.data = snapshot.val();
            console.log($scope.data)
            processData($scope); //call that function here
        });

});
```